# How do I implement hook_views_pre_render()?

Tags: views, hooks

I need to alter the result of a view. I read I can use `hook_views_pre_render()`, but in a custom module. I don't have any custom module implemented and I would like to know where and how should I put the code in my project.

Comment: See [Module developer's guide](https://drupal.org/developing/modules).

Comment: You can also put this in a theme, so, if you are already doing custom work there, and don't "need" a custom module, it can be added to this theme's template.php or other appropriate php file.  Realize, of course, that this pre_rendering would only apply when this theme is active.

Comment: @Jimajamma I'm pretty sure this hook doesn't get called for themes - are you thinking of `_alter` hooks or have I got it wrong?

Comment: Nope, @clive, I even looked it up to make sure that it does (comment:  `// Let the themes play too, because pre render is a very themey thing.`) in Views' `includes/view.inc`

Comment: Quite welcome.  Interestingly enough, there is no `theme_implements()` so this doesn't even need a cache clear to be picked up. Not that I just threw together a quick "hello world" `bartik_views_pre_render()` to be doubly certain or anything...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read and understand the [Module developer's guide](https://drupal.org/developing/modules) first, then it's as simple as adding the following to your .module file:

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  // Do stuff with the $view object.
}
```

Comment: Also if you are really going to get into developing custom modules (which I found pretty useful pretty early on in my Drupal experience) I found the book [Pro Drupal 7 Development](http://www.drupalbook.com/code-drupal-like-a-pro) very helpful. 

It not only explains how to set up your own modules, more importantly for me it gives you an overview of the drupal workflow so you can get an idea of how and where the hook function are being called.

Answer (score 0):

Views hooks should be implemented in a .views.inc files not in .module file